# I cannot expand RAID 5 capacity on an Adaptec RAID 71605

Tags: configuration, raid5, adaptec, expansion

I have a Supermicro CSE-815 X8DTU-F server.

In it I have installed an Adaptec RAID 71605 controller with 4 SAS HDDs.

With them I set up a RAID 5 with 3 discs only. Now I have connected the disk that was catching and I want to expand it to a RAID5 with the 4 disks.

I have done all the management of the adapter through "maxView Storage Manager" but at the moment of expanding the RAID it does not let me add the new disk. It just appears but doesn't let me select (see image).

[image: Try to add hdd]

It is my first post and I hope I have explained myself. I don't know if someone has hit him and can help me or is it some wrong configuration.

I think I have found the problem.
Reviewing the screenshot I see that the new HDD detects it with 1,023 GB less (1047.55 MB less). This does not make sense since the 4 HDDs are identical.
The disk is empty so I don't know why it says it is smaller.
How can I reduce the size of the RAID 5 or fix this?

Answer (score 1):

To expand the array using maxView Storage Manager:

1. In the Enterprise View, select a controller.
2. On the ribbon, in the "Controller" group, click Set Properties and then Data Protection. Verify that the RAID Consistency Check is disabled. Click OK.
3. Select the logical device to be changed in the Enterprise View.
4. On the ribbon, in the "Logical Device" group, click Expand/Migrate. A wizard opens.
5. In order to expand the capacity of an existing array, select the same RAID level, then click next.
6. In the RAID members panel, select the drive(s) or drive segments to be added to the RAID array. Click next.
7. Enter the size of the logical drive in the space provided (in gigabytes). It must be greater than or equal to the current size. Click next.
8. Review the logical drive settings and click finish to start the reconfiguration.

[https://ask.adaptec.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/15127/~/how-to-expand-the-capacity-of-a-raid-array-using-adaptec%2Ficp-or-maxview-storage](https://ask.adaptec.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/15127/%7E/how-to-expand-the-capacity-of-a-raid-array-using-adaptec%2Ficp-or-maxview-storage)

Comment: Hello Christopher H.
Thanks for your answer.
The steps you indicate are the ones I have been doing so far.
The problem is that I cannot select the HDD to expand the RAID5. As can be seen in the image, it appears in gray and you cannot put the check to select it (Slot 31). This prevents the process from continuing and expands the drive.
Any idea why it happens?

Comment: This is because of your browser version. Chrome/Edge Chromium work. Pretty much everything else does not.